# TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function message when I'm trying to export named class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to test components. I already have a default export and believe I have to use a named class for my next export. Here is the code:

```
export default Users;

import React from 'react';

export class UsersTest extends React.Users {
    updateState(event) {
      this.setState({
          input: event.target.value
      });
    }
    render() {
      return <div><input
        onChange={this.updateState.bind(this)}
        type="text" /></div>;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The component you are trying to make extends from is undefined.
React doesn't have a 'Users' property.
In your case, it looks like you need to make the extension from Users, not React.Users.